# How to run program in MATLAB in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, swing

I have a Java application running in Eclipse and another application in MATLAB. Now I want to launch MATLAB application in my Java application. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You can use `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec` to start other programs running.

Comment: Ok thanx a lot ,I will see it .